# OrientDB - Search by json attribute inside column

Tags: json, orientdb

I have a graph with following structure:

- @rid
- @class
- @version
- *content* (json content)

The column `_content_` stores a json like `{"phoneNumber":"+5511999998888","date":"2017-05-09T18:23:31Z"}`.

I would like to perform a search by `date` attribute where the value is lower than another value.

Is  possible to run a query like that with the folowing structure? How can  I write the select condition? I'm kinda new to OrientDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your vertex name is Person

You can do :

```
CREATE PROPERTY Person.content IF NOT EXISTS EMBEDDED
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE content.date < "2017-05-09T18:23:31Z"
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the doc section about sql : http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL.html